# Create index from column values with no repetitions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with Countries and their continent. Of course, there are countries that belongs to the same continent.
I want column Continent to be the index, but I want no repetitions.
Right now I have just been able to create the index, but I have several Europe, several Asia, etc.

Data frame:

[image: df]

Example of what I want:

[image: example of what I want]

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what would you want to have in the index column instead of duplicating those continents? An example of your data frame and expected output added as text to the question would be useful

Comment: I have added a picture of my actual output. What I want is one apparition per continent in the index.

Comment: A picture isn't particularly helpful

Comment: you should add an example of a few rows of your df as *text* (using df.head() will work if you only have a few columns).  Then a text example of what you'd want the index to look like instead of having repeats

Comment: The image shows an example of my actual dataframe.
What I want is to have unique values for the index, so it looks like the second image I have added (the example is from another exercise, it has nothing to do with my actual dataframe, but it shows perfectly how I want to to be)

Comment: [please post example code/data as text NOT images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code%20%28or%20error%2Fexception%20messages%2C,and%20compiled%20in%20order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
dfx=df.groupby(['country','rank_level']).agg({'column_name_want_to_mean':'mean','column_name_want_to_max':'max'})
```